:GetChildren() seemingly returning an empty table?
so im trying to make a little casino game on roblox for fun and for whatever reason it refuses to find anything inside of the folder where you place your bet in the machine
here's the script (the print functions are temporary and it will not print "Found betplacer")
local p = game.Players.LocalPlayer

function canBet()
    return true--p:FindFirstChild("CanBet").Value
end

function bet(event:RemoteEvent, racer:Instance, tokens:number)
    if canBet() then
        event:FireServer(tokens, racer)
    end
end

for _, machine in pairs(workspace.Machines:GetChildren()) do
    if machine.Name == "RacingHeads" then
        local placers = machine.Placers:GetChildren()

        print("Found RacingHeads")

        for _, v in pairs(placers) do
            local event = v.Parent.Parent:FindFirstChild("Bet")
            local racer = v:FindFirstChild("Racer").Value
            local gui = v:FindFirstChild("BetGui")
            local button:TextButton = gui.Submit
            local function quickbet()
                local tokens = tonumber(gui.Amount.Text)

                print("Bet on RacingHeads")
                bet(event, racer, tokens)
            end

            print("Found betplacer")

            button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(quickbet)
            button.TouchTap:Connect(quickbet)
        end
    end
end


Please check out this guide: [mre]. Roblox questions can be hard to create MREs for, but some good guidelines are to start by focusing heavily on the "minimal" part (what is the absolute simplest example you can create that still produces a similar problem), then provide thorough details as to how to reproduce the problem - the code of course, but also any objects that should go in the workspace and how they should be organized.

this is likely because of Streaming Enabled. A simple fix would be to disable it. It's a property of workspace
